# Why Bearer word is required at the starting of the token

Tags: authentication, oauth, bearer-token

What is difference between following two authorization

```
Authorization : Bearer as458asde458er


Authorization : as458asde458er
```

Comment: almost exactly the same question came up (and was answered) here: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/108662/why-is-bearer-required-before-the-token-in-authorization-header-in-a-http-re which would be a better duplicate target, but is on another stackexchange site.

Answer (score 0):

There's different kind of authentication mechanisms. `Bearer` is one of them, `Basic` and `Digest` are some examples of others.

The `Authorization` HTTP header is defined that it starts with what 'type' of authentication is used. It also allows multiple types to be used as the same time.